# How do I add a SwipeView to CollectionView when adding a new "Note" in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am currently making a note-taking app for a school project. I don't have too much experience so excuse me.

I would like to add a SwipeView to my CollectionView when a new item is adding to the list of "notes" which will allow the user to delete the note.

I have used the default flyout layout in xamarin to help me out.

ItemsPage xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="xamarinMobileTest.Views.ItemsPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xamarinMobileTest.ViewModels"  
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:xamarinMobileTest.Models"  
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Add Note" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <RefreshView x:DataType="local:ItemsViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <SwipeView>
                        <SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <SwipeItems Mode="Execute">
                                <SwipeItem Text="Delete" 
                                           BackgroundColor="Red"
                                           Invoked="SwipeItem_Invoked"/>
                            </SwipeItems>
                        </SwipeView.RightItems>
                        <StackLayout Padding="5" x:DataType="model:Item">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}"
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                                FontSize="16"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                TextColor="Black"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="13"
                                TextColor="Black"/>
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"     
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                                </TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </SwipeView>
                </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage>
```

This is what I have so far and when trying to save a note the app crashes.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I create a Shell projec to test with SwipeView. No error. Please check my screenshot: https://imgur.com/0pBCrLk You could create a new Shell project to check again.

Comment: Could you please share your code? Whenever I add the SwipeView to my CollectionView I get an exception thrown at me when I click on the browse tab in a new project. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

Comment: I have posted the code. But I think it is similar. Check the screenshot: https://imgur.com/o9DchtU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

I needed to add this piece of code into my app.xamls.cs

```
    Device.SetFlags(new string[] { "SwipeView_Experimental", "AppTheme_Experimental" });
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you may have error in specify the `command`

in the datatemplate

try to fix like this:

```
  Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference BrowseItemsPage},Path=ItemTapped"
```

`ItemTapped` is your Command in your `viewmodel`.

Answer (score 0):

The orignal code with Shell Template and add a SwipeView:

```
 <RefreshView x:DataType="local:ItemsViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <SwipeView>
                    <SwipeView.RightItems>
                        <SwipeItems Mode="Execute">
                            <SwipeItem Text="Delete" 
                                       BackgroundColor="Red"
                                       Invoked="SwipeItem_Invoked"/>
                        </SwipeItems>
                    </SwipeView.RightItems>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:Item">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                        LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                        Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                        FontSize="16" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
                        LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                        Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                        FontSize="13" />
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"     
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                            </TapGestureRecognizer>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    </StackLayout>
                </SwipeView>
                
              
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</RefreshView>
```

I have checked the you code. It still works.

Comment: Weird. I have tested your code on two separate original shell templates one on a flyout template and another on the tabbed template and whenever I open the "browse" tab with the code implemented the app crashes. I don't Know if its an issue on my end or what?